# Gulp js src : get deepest files first

Tags: javascript, gulp, reactjs

I use Gulp to build a small web application based on the React framework.

To compile the client scripts, my task starts like that :

```
gulp.task( 'buildClientScripts', function () {
    // Get all the js and jsx scripts
    // Starts with the app.js file
    return gulp.src( [
            'app/app.js',
            'app/clientScripts/**/*.jsx',
            'app/clientScripts/**/*.js',
        ] )
```

The order of the files is my problem. For this file structure :

```
- clientScripts
---- components
-------- subComponents
------------ mysubComponent.js
-------- myComponent.js
---- main.js
```

The load order will be : `main.js`, `myComponent.js`, `mysubComponent.js`. But obviously, my top files need the deeper files to work.

How do I ask gulp to load the deepest files first ?

Comment: If you have an explicit order, you should list them in that order. Otherwise, use a dependency manager like [Require](http://requirejs.org/) to order them as needed.

Comment: This was for the example. In a real world app, I will have hundreds of files. I do not want to require each file everywhere I need them and set the order in the gulp list is out of question. This is why the `'app/clientScripts/**/*.jsx'` is for. The file load order in Meteor (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) is a good example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gulp-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sort) to order the files after `gulp.src` reads them.

Count slashes in path as crude way to determine depth.

```
var sort = require('gulp-sort');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task( 'buildClientScripts', function () {
    // Get all the js and jsx scripts
    // Starts with the app.js file
    return gulp.src( [
        'app/app.js',
        'app/clientScripts/**/*.jsx',
        'app/clientScripts/**/*.js',
    ] )
    .pipe(sort(function(file1, file2) {
      return countSlashes(file2) - countSlashes(file1);

      function countSlashes(file) {
        return file.path.split(path.sep).length - 1;
      }
    })
```